# KDL, undefined reference to KDL::Chain

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I am having problems when trying to compile with rosmake a KDL example (the one found in the KDL website). I always get this output when doing rosmake

undefined reference to `KDL::Chain::~Chain()'

and a lot more of undefined reference... i did everything i could.. followed the ros instructions in order to get kdl up and running but i cannot get it to compile!

Note: i included the find_package(Orocos-kdl) in the CMakeLists but the problem persists...

Any help will be appreciated!
thanks in advance,
Franco

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76231/kdl,-undefined-reference-to-kdl::chain/) by [Franco](https://answers.ros.org/users/6352/franco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get it compiled and linked!

For everyone:
in the CMakeLists:

add:

```
project(prueba_kdl)

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Orocos-KDL REQUIRED)

rosbuild_add_executable(prueba_kdl src/prueba.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} orocos-kdl)
```

Cheers
Franco

---

Originally posted by [Franco](https://answers.ros.org/users/6352/franco/) with karma: 36 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey! hello
I had the exact same problem, but I was trying the tutorial for parsing a URDF to use the KDL library. Here is my solution:
I also edit the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(kdl_beginner)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

find_package(orocos_kdl)
find_package(kdl_parser)

add_executable(mykdl src/mykdl.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mykdl ${kdl_parser_LIBRARIES}   ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES} )
```

:D

BTW I am on ubuntu 12.04 running groovy

---

Originally posted by [moicez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5207/moicez/) with karma: 11 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1